# Vue/ Nuxt - run code after the entire view has been rendered?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to create a few functions after after the  entire view has been rendered / [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted):

```
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    this.example = function() {
      return 'example'
    },
    function() {
      console.log('mounted') // does not work
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log(this.example()) // error
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage() {
      console.log(this.example()) // example
    }
  }
}
```

Why do I get the error below at `created()`?

```
TypeError: this.example is not a function
    at VueComponent.created (index.vue:119)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:2661)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js:4222)
    at VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4392)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:3674)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js:3491)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:5143)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js:5086)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js:5602)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js:2420)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about Vue.set? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: @RichardMatsen any good examples how I can use `set`?

Comment: Actually, I think @asemahle has nailed it - the order of the hooks is created then mounted, so add your functions in the created hook (and test them in mounted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created` hook is called *before* the `mounted` hook. When the `created()` function runs, `this.example` has not yet been declared.

You will be able to call `this.created()` after it has been declared.

Refer to the [lifecycle diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).